# How to determine how much the map *will* move by without moving it

Tags: openlayers

I have an application where the markers move regularly, and I call

```
map.getView().fit(extent, {size: map.getSize(), padding: [150,150,150,150], duration: 6000});
```

To resize the map to zoom to the extent required to show all the active markers.

When there is a small number of markers that have moved a small distance this results in the map moving just a few pixels left / right randomly where it doesn't actually show any additional information (markers)

Is it possible (or how is it best to) determine what movement this would cause in advance or is there a simple way to determine if all the markers on screen are within X distance of the centre point and therefore don't move at all.

I know I can use `onScreen()` however if the marker was right on the edge then this would return `true` and I'd rather it *did* resize in that situation.

Then logic I'm looking for is basically "if all markers are within the centre 75% or so of the area displayed, don't resize / move it"

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the extent of 75% if the visible map (based on the current center) and only move if the new extent is not completely contained within that

```
var size = map.getSize();
var visible75pc = map.getView().calculateExtent([size[0] * 0.75, size[1] * 0.75]);
if (!ol.extent.containsExtent(visible75pc, extent) {
  map.getView().fit(extent, options);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of using calculateExtent, will try that :)